# Front end for a user theory plugin?

Tags: z3

Is it possible to use smt-lib or similar APIs for C/C++ to parse the inputs for a user theory plugins? E.g, in the example user theory "test_user_theory.c", how to declare a string variable and a constant string (without breaking it into bit vectors) in the input file? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The functions `z3_parse_smtlib_string`, `z3_parse_smtlib_file`, `z3_parse_smtlib2_string`, `z3_parse_smtlib2_file` allow the user to bind arbitrary symbols with given sorts and declarations.
Thus, you can connect a finite number of symbols with declarations defined in your theory plugin. This is not a perfect solution, since some theories define an arbitrary number of function/constant declarations and sorts. For example, theory of arithmetic defines the symbols: `0`, `1`, `2`, etc. The array theory defines an "infinite" number of sorts.

Note that the theory plugin API is now obsolete. The Z3 source code is now available, and extensions to the Z3 theorem prover can be directly implemented inside the actual code base. The Z3 source code is available at http://z3.codeplex.com. I'm planning to remove the theory plugin API in future releases.